# xamarin automatically adjust webview height

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

How to configure Xamarin Webview to display an automatic height according to html content?
I am developing a news app in Xamarin and I have this problem, because the webview forces me to inform the height and the width to display the information and as my content is dynamic, (always changes) ends up being an empty space on screen!

Sorry for english, I used google translate!

Thanks!

Code: PostView.cs

```
namespace AppNewsPlay.Views
{


    public partial class PostView : TabbedPage
    {
        private int object_id;

        // Criando a Listagem de Ultimas Noticias Playstation
        List<PostViewModels> UPost; 

        public TabbedPage Detail { get; private set; }


        public PostView(int object_id)
        {

            this.object_id = object_id;
            UPost = new List<PostViewModels>();
            ObterPost();

            InitializeComponent();       


        }



        private async void ObterPost()
        {
            var resp = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var uri = new HttpClient()
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.newsplay.com.br")
                };
                var url = "/api/post/" + this.object_id;
                var result = await uri.GetAsync(url);


                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão", "Não foi possível obter as notícias do servidor, Tente novamente mais tarde!", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão com o Servidor", ex.Message, "OK");
                return;

            }

            // transformando o retorno em objeto através do json e deserealize e retornando em lista
            var UPost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PostViewModels>>(resp);

            var browser = new WebView();


          // var htmlsource = new UrlWebViewSource();

            foreach (var item in UPost)
            {
            var  html = item.Guid;
                browser.Source = html;

            }


            //   Adicionando os itens ao ListView na Home.xaml - Aba Playstation*/
            PostViewList.ItemsSource = UPost;
            //     ProgressLoader.IsRunning = false;



        }
```

Code: PostView.xaml

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppNewsPlay.Views.PostView"
             Title="Voltar"
             Icon=""
             BarBackgroundColor="#1c9e33"
            >

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage Title="Notícia" Icon="ic_filter_list_black_24dp.png">

            <ContentPage.Content >
                <StackLayout
                        Spacing="20">      

                    <ListView x:Name="PostViewList"
                                HasUnevenRows="True"      
                                SeparatorColor="White"
                                SeparatorVisibility="Default"                                                                  
                                >

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout
                                               Padding="20"                                
                                               Orientation="Vertical"                                        
                                               >                                       

                                        <Label x:Name="Post_title" Text="{ Binding Post_title }"
                                                 FontSize="20"
                                                 FontAttributes="Bold"  
                                                 HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                 />

                                        <Label x:Name="Post_ad" Text="{Binding Post_ad}"
                                                       FontSize="12"                                            
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"   
                                                       />


                                        <WebView HorizontalOptions= "FillAndExpand"
                                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                 HeightRequest="3500" 
                                                 WidthRequest="650"
                                                 x:Name="browser"
                                                 Source="{Binding Guid}"                                            

                                             >


                                        </WebView>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>


    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```